# Сборка проекта под x32 на 64-й системе. Ошибка 'unsupported machine mode 'tc''

Tags: c++, c, qt, makefile, сборка

Пытаюсь собрать библиотеку qserialdevice на 64-битной архитектуре. Добавил поддержку пакетов для 32-битной архитектуры, в том числе и **gcc-multilib**. При попытке собрать библиотеку (make) выдает ошибку:

```
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:30,
                 from /usr/local/arm-linux-4.4.2/lib/gcc/arm-linux/4.4.2/../../../../arm-linux/include/c++/4.4.2/cwchar:47,
...
/usr/include/bits/floatn.h:75: ошибка: неизвестная машинный режим ‘TC’
/usr/include/bits/floatn.h:87: ошибка: ‘__float128’ does not name a type
```

Установил так же пакет **arm-linux-gnueabi**. В нем есть библиотека floatn.h без поддержки чисел с 4-х кратной точностью, но его библиотеки сохранились в /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi. Компилируется с помощью **xscale-linux-g++**

Добавлю. Перенес все на виртуальную машину debian архитектуры i386. Ошибка все та же. Может, библиотека floatn.h входит в какой то пакет, который я устанавил?

Comment: Откуда там вообще arm вылезает?

Comment: в нем есть библиотеки и программы необходимые для работы коммутатора. xscale-linux-g++ используется им же и находится в нем. программа, собственно, пишется для него.

Comment: ну как бы тогда естесnвенно, что их не получается собрать под x32...

Comment: все исполняемые файлы в arm-... работают только на 32-битной архитектуре, так что с ним все в порядке.

Comment: и там пропущены строки вывода где стоят ... . не arm собирается, собирается совсем другой преокт, используя инструменты из arm. некоторые проекты собираются, но именно этот - нет.

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ uname -a`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Забыл закрыть вопрос. Проблема решена. Причиной оказался сам gcc-multilib, в который и входит библиотека floatn.h. Размещенный в /usr/lib, он подключался первее, чем тот, который был прописан в makefile. Поэтому такая ошибка и возникала. Спасибо

Решением в моем случае стало перенос проекта на виртуальную машину с архитектурой i386 и сборка на нем.

Comment: `-m 32` Надо вам было в сборочном файле указывать. Или кросс-компиляцию делать.